# File is not received server side with multer file/data upload

Tags: node.js

In my flutter application, I am trying to upload a file to the server from client side using MultipartRequest in flutter.

The client side code to upload the data is as follows:

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

        request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'file', 
          photo.photo,
          filename: basename(photo.path), 
        ));

      
        request.fields['ID'] = documentID!;


On the server side, using nodejs and typescript, I try to receive the uploaded data as follows, but the body and everything is always empty/null:

const upload = multer({
  dest: "/tmp/uploads/", // Use /tmp for temporary file storage
}); 


app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Body keys:", Object.keys(req.body)); // Empty
  console.log("Received upload request");
  console.log("Headers_:", req.headers);
  console.log("Body:", req.body);  // empty
  // Check for ID
  const ID = req.body.ID || req.query.ID;
  if (!ID) {
    console.log("Missing ID in the request");
    return res.status(400).send("ID is required.");
  } else {
    console.log(`Received messageId: ${ID}`);
  }
```

-- What can i do in order to receive the data for processing server side?

Any help is will be fully appriciated!